# Set multiple values to nodata - Erdas Imagine 2015

Tags: erdas-imagine, landsat-8, nodata, reflectance, surface

I am having trouble with the data ranges in the Landsat 8 surface reflectance product which I downloaded from USGS. The Lansat 8 surface reflectance handbook says the valid range is 0 - 10,000 range but the product may come with values between -2000 to 16000. I am using the level 2 landsat 8 surface reflectance product with a view to detecting sediment plumes exiting glaciers by thresholding.

I want to know how to do the following on Erdas Imagine 2015 to:

1. exclude the values outwith the valid range (0 - 10,000)
2. apply the scale factor of 0.0001 in order to convert reflectance values to a scale from 0 to 1.

Is there a way to apply the Set to NoData function in the Spatial Model Maker to multiple values - say those values that are < 0 and > 10,000 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rescale Landsat 8 surface reflectance data ranges in Erdas Imagine 2015?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290492/rescale-landsat-8-surface-reflectance-data-ranges-in-erdas-imagine-2015)

Comment: Apologies I was rephrasing it and now realise I should have edited the original post instead